# Login using php

Tags: php, curl

I have tried the following code for login authentication but its not working.

```
<?php
define('URL', 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com');
function authenticate($uname, $pass) {

    $url = URL . 'Issue/Bug-5555';

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$uname:$pass");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // ssl ensure cert
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1); /// ssl ensure cert

    $issue_list = (curl_exec($curl));
    echo $issue_list;

    return $issue_list;
}   ?>
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: yes i'm getting false message only

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few issues with English in your post.  Please explain what is not working.  Does it give an error, does it hang up ?

Comment: when i trying to authenticate with valid username and password but i got null value.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what you are trying to achieve with this code.
Are you trying to get a ticket info, post an issue? You are just using the API...

Well here's a script that works with the JIRA API.

```
<?php
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';
$url = "https://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.net/rest/api/2/project";

$ch = curl_init();

$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$test = "This is the content of the custom field.";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$ch_error = curl_error($ch);

if ($ch_error) {
    echo "cURL Error: $ch_error";
} else {
    echo $result;
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This code is fetching a project from JIRA.
If you want to create issues, you will have to change the REST URL to /rest/api/2/issue/ and use "POST" instead of "GET" method.

Comment: flag as a duplicate then, you are not really providing an answer

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a slash in the URL. The `$url` you pass to cURL currently has value:

```
https://jira.hawkdefense.comIssue/Bug-5555
```

After the `curl_exec()` line, insert this and copy/paste the result here.

```
if (curl_errno($url)) {
  throw new Exception(curl_error($url));
}
```